# Problema con los acentos en url

Tags: php, codeigniter

Consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Codigo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Link:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ejemplo un link : localhost/codeigneter/search/region-de-arica-y-parinacota/aysen

Comment: Cuál es el problema?

Comment: @Jemonge url amigables a los titulos de un contenido para reemplazar caracteres especiales y espacios. no entiendo que salio "regi%E3%93n"

Comment: pega tu código en vez de las imágenes, para que podamos probar las expresiones regulares de nuestro lado.

Comment: @DiegoSagredo, por favor, la próxima ves **incluye el código**, no una imagen del mismo.

Comment: @DiegoSagredo, ¿aún no has podido solucionar tu problema?

Answer (score 2):

En vez de listar manualmente los caracteres "problemáticos", lo que puedes hacer es una expresión regular para decir: "todos los caracteres no ASCII".

Los caracteres ASCII son los que están entre `\x00` y `\x7F`.([Esto lo aprendí en StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203190/regex-any-ascii-character)) Los caracteres *imprimibles* ASCII están entre el `\x20` y `\x7F`, por lo tanto para eliminar todo lo que no caiga en ese rango haces:

```
$jstring2 = preg_replace('/[^(\x20-\x7F)]*/', '', $jcountry);
```

De ahí en adelante queda a tu criterio qué hacer con los espacios y signos de puntuación.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que estas buscando es generar una `URL` sin caracteres especiales, como por ejemplo: `/search/region-de-arica-y-parinacota/aysen`

Lo que te estaría faltando hacer es reemplazar cada `caracter acentuado` con su correspondiente *sin acento*.

Ejemplo:

```
<?php

function urlCleanString($str) {
    // Quitamos los caracteres "desconocidos"
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9ñÑáéíóúÁÉÍÓÚ ]/', '', $str);

    // Reemplazamos los espacios por guiones (-)
    $str = strtolower(preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', $str));

    // Reemplazamos la caracteres acentuados
    return str_replace(array('á','é','í','ó','ú','ñ'), array('a','e','i','o','u','n'), $str);
}

$jcountry = 'Región de arica y parinacota';
$jcity = 'Aysén';

echo 'search/'.urlCleanString($jcountry).'/'.urlCleanString($jcity);

//Output: search/region-de-arica-y-parinacota/aysen
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/AEES95476)</kbd>

**PD**: Tu `RegExp` para quitar *"caracteres desconocidos"* le faltaba incluir el espacio () y por eso tus `$paramN` no tenían guiones (`-`)

Answer (score 0):

En realidad es bastante simple:

Cargamos el helper text en el controlador, donde lo necesites o directamente en el autoload

```
// Cargamos el helper
$this->load->helper('text');

// Forma de Implementación
$str = 'áéíóú';
$str = convert_accented_characters($str);
echo $str; // aeiou
```